# trying to compare a string with contents of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some python code that tries to compare the contents of a list within a dictionary, with a string.
It's failing because the format is slightly different.

Here's what I see in my logs:

```
root - INFO - =============
root - INFO - {"email": ["123@yahoo.com", "23343@yahoo.com"]}
root - INFO - "{'email': ['123@yahoo.com', '23343@yahoo.com']}"
root - INFO - =============
```

And here's the code that produces this output:

```
logging.info("=============")
test = str(json.dumps({'email':dictemail['email']}))
logging.info(test)
logging.info(emailstring)
logging.info("=============")

if test == emailstring:
    return True
```

I'm just new to python so I apologize for the noob question.  But "dictemail" is the dictionary... and at key 'email' i have a list.
I've tried a few different things but I can't seem to format the contents of dictemail in such a way that the comparison will pass.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if the formatting is reliably always the same, you could use Python's .replace() method.

```
>>> emailstring = "{'email': ['123@yahoo.com', '23343@yahoo.com']}"
>>> emailstring = emailstring.replace('"','').replace("'",'"')
>>> print(emailstring)
{"email": ["123@yahoo.com", "23343@yahoo.com"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `dictemail` is a dictionary and the variable `test` is a string, so they can never be equal to one another. In order to compare them, I would either convert the dictionary `dictemail` to a json string or converting the json string `test` to a proper dictionary. I think the latter is more robust.

```
if json.loads(test) == dictemail:
    return True
```